# Max() in LINQ Query

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a Column with DataType as Nvarchar(max)
Sample Records:

```
Advisor_Code
9001
9002
9003
100001
100001
9011
```

I have tried this Query :

```
var code = (from a in db.advisor_Registration select a ).Max(a=>a.advisor_Code);
```

It Returns 9011 but max Number is 100001 .
How to fix it

Comment: Your column needs to be an integer, not a varchar.

Comment: You don't have numbers, you have strings. `9011 < 100001`, but `"9011" > "100001"`. The normal approach for handling this would be using the correct data type. Presumably you have a nvarchar type because some of your codes cannot be interpreted as numbers, but if you do, how do you want to treat them in comparisons?

Comment: @hvd I understand but is there any thing like this : select max(cast(advisor_code as int)) From table

Comment: @King_Fisher Yes, there is, but to be clear, in SQL that would fail badly if *any* of the codes cannot be cast to an int. You're okay with getting exceptions if you have any such codes in your database? If so, that's relevant information worth including in the question.

Comment: @hvd there is no chance for that exception because i have only the above values in my Table

Answer (score 2):

Since one of the tags is [entity-framework](/questions/tagged/entity-framework) I assume it should be translatable into SQL. If you use e.g. `Convert.ToInt32` in the LINQ statement, this won't succeed.

A common way to get the "numeric" max out of strings without conversion is to order by length and then by string:

```
var max = myquery.OrderByDescending(x => x.Length)
                 .ThenByDescending (x => x)
                 .First();
```

where `myquery` could be any query against a `DbSet` that returns strings. Of course the results will be meaningless if any of the strings is not numeric.

Comment: Still the Same Result 9011

Comment: I have this:   var code = db.advisor_Registration.OrderByDescending(x => x.advisor_Code)
                 .ThenByDescending(x => x)
                 .First();

Comment: That's different. Look at the `Length` part.

Comment: `myquery` should return *strings*. Like `db.advisor_Registration.Select(x => x.advisor_Code).OrderByDescending`...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67640/discussion-between-king-fisher-and-gert-arnold).

Comment: getting this value on Var "System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Advisor_Registration_693A3F85F8E1A62A77430B179FDC93BBFCD4C418168D03DA90544BED307DC5B8" string
"

Comment: What does `db.advisor_Registration.Select(x => x.advisor_Code)` return?

Comment: returns values frommy Table what i have mentioned above

Comment: I have this now :var code = db.advisor_Registration.Select(c=>c.advisor_Code).OrderByDescending(x => x.Length)
                 .ThenByDescending(x => x)
                 .First(); it returns values ""System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Advisor_Registration_693A3F85F8E1A62A77430B17‌​9FDC93BBFCD4C418168D03DA90544BED307DC5B8" string "

Comment: Something must be wrong with your code. How can `Max(a=>a.advisor_Code)` return 9011 and a `First` advisor_Code return a proxy name???

Comment: you'd need an extra step here to handle negative values.

Answer (score 0):

You can only perform a MAX function with your expected result on a numeric field.  nvarchar(max) is not a numeric field.  You would have to convert the strings to a long, for example, then take the MAX for MAX to work as you are expecting.

Comment: You clearly can perform a max on a string field. The OP is doing that, and getting a result. It's just not the result the OP was expecting.

Comment: I'll reword my answer so your twitchy downvote finger is happy.

Comment: It then still is not necessarily a useful answer. It will fail rather badly if any of the strings cannot be parsed as a number. (That's why I commented on the question requestion clarification, instead of posting an answer, by the way.)

Comment: How to convert the String to Long in this Query ?